# English approximations of Spanish pronouns

Tags: pronouns, dialects, spanish

Excuse me if this question sounds familiar, but I've searched and couldn't find what I desired.

In the Spanish second-person, there is *usted* (formal), *tú* (familiar), and *ustedes* (plural for both).

In Argentina, the role of *tú* is usurped by *vos*, and in Spain, the role of the familiar *ustedes* is (usually) usurped by *vosotros*.

With these verbs comes different conjugation:

- You are
- Usted es
- Tú eres
- Ustedes son
- Vos sos
- Vosotros sois

I'm not a native Spanish speaker but these all seem very natural to me now, and when using them you can understand how they came to be and why they exist in the way they do.

I'm helping my friend with his Spanish and I've told him that there are a few concepts in Spanish that don't exist in English and can't really be translated, diversity in second-person pronouns being one of them.

This got me thinking, though. Are there any English dialects where *you* isn't simply used for any possible reference to the second-person? *Y'all* is often considered as a rough approximation of *ustedes* and *vosotros*. Is this as far as it goes? Any others? And what's so different about English that causes it to not develop in the way that Spanish does?

Comment: Actually, in many US dialects which use it, "y'all" is singular. The plural is "all y'all". As far as what's so different: EVERY language is different in ways ranging from trivial to profound. It's purely a matter of history and evolution. You can ask _how_ divergences might have occurred when there's a common root, but the answer to "why" is "because."

Comment: In various places in the USA, "yiz, y'all, youse, you guys, youse guys," etc. are common in colloquial lects. In England, there are plenty of places, especially in the Northern counties, where no American is likely to recognize **any** of the pronouns without a local guide. Moreover, local usage of _tú_ and _usted_ varies, as well. In Mexican Spanish _usted_ is reserved for very important people, and _tú_ is used with almost everybody, though _ustedes_ is the normal plural.

Comment: Related regarding the plural pronoun: *[Did English ever have a “you” plural?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22194)*, *[Which English dialects have 2nd person plural?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/83643)*, *[The case of “y'all”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/117396)*, *[What is the proper usage of “Y'all” in southern American dialects](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8102)*, *[Origins of the south-western Pennsylvania slang word “Yinz”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/69341)*, and others.

Comment: Related regarding formal/respectful forms: *[Did English ever have a formal version of “you”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9780)*, *[“Thou” or “You”? This is the problem!](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/138925)*, *[In what region is “thou”, etc. used in dialect?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25288/)*. Hmm, should we have a tag for T-V distinction?

Comment: You missed one version: the original *vos sois* or *vos podéis* instead of the Rioplantense norm of *vos sos* or *vos podés*; it’s an archaic 2nd-person-formal now reserved ironic or affected use with kings and popes and such. The [entire *voseo* situation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voseo) is actually ***unbelievably* more complicated** than “oh, just replace *tú* with *vos*” might lead you to believe. Concordance, especially of clitics, is nearly peculiar to each region, and subjunctives might switch. There’re even places in America with three-way opposition between *tú, vos,* and *Usted*.

Comment: @tchrist Does that entail a three-way distinction in politeness as well, or is it used for something else? (I take it there is no corresponding plural three-way opposition?)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yes, that’s right. See the referenced article for places where “a three-tiered system is used, that indicates the degree of respect or trust: *usted, tú, vos. Usted* expresses distance and respect; *tú* corresponds to an intermediate level, expressing familiarity, but not deep trust; *vos* remains the pronoun of maximum familiarity and solidarity, and also lack of respect.” This is like Iberian Portuguese’s unofficial *o/a senhor/a → você → tu* sequence. The only thing like 3-way for plural would be *los señores → Ustedes → vosotros* in Spain, but the first is waiter-talk. :)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Oh definitely read the [Spanish version on *voseo*](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voseo): it’s much more nuanced and covers several curiosities unmentioned in the English version. For example, how in Honduras “El uso del tuteo es mal visto entre hombres.” What, it’s ok for girls but not guys? Also the *ustedeo* discussion at the very end there and [on its own page](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ustedeo). Curious indeed.

Comment: @keshlam: I wouldn't say there are *many* dialects where *y'all* is singular, since in most of the South it's plural. There are definitely *some*.

Comment: @PeterShor: I've been corrected enough times that I presumed singular y'all was more common. I'm certainly willing to believe I've just been talking to the wrong subset. After all, I'm from the part of the country where a /yôl/ is a two-masted sailing vessel.

Answer (score 8):

> Are there any English dialects where *you* isn't simply used for any possible reference to the second-person? *Y'all* is often considered as a rough approximation of *ustedes* and *vosotros*. Is this as far as it goes? Any others?

There are still a few spots of dialects left in the northern parts of the UK and Scotland where a different second person singular pronoun, the modern development of the older standard *thou*, has persisted [in various forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thou#Current_usage), mostly pronounced [ða] or [ðə], sometimes [ðɛ].

As John Lawler says in his comment, there are many more variations than just *y’all*; *y’all* just happens to be the most common one. I don’t think there are any English-speaking areas that *don’t* have some kind of ‘double plural’ to mark a specifically plural *you*, be it *y’all*, *yiz*, *youse*, *y’uns*, *yous’uns*, *all y’all*, or even the almost comical *alls y’alls’uns*, which by my count marks its pluralness no less than five (!) times.

> And what's so different about English that causes it to not develop in the way that Spanish does?

Nothing. Nothing whatsoever.

You see, *every single language on the planet* develops in its own, unique way.

- Some develop an intricate, elaborate, and confusing system of pronouns (Japanese, for example, has an intricate system of pronouns that depend on both the gender and social status of, as well as the speaker’s attitude towards not only the speaker and the addressee, but also the physical antecedent of the pronoun);
- others develop very simple systems (standard Mandarin—if we exclude various dialectal or extremely formulaic forms, as well as artificial orthographical choices—has no case, gender, or numerus distinctions and makes do with just three in total, one for each person);
- and others yet never develop a system of personal pronouns at all (Vietnamese, for example, uses conventionalised nouns rather than actual pronouns).

So it’s not that there is something ‘different’ about English that makes it not develop like Spanish, but rather that they’re different languages and therefore, quite unavoidably, develop in different ways.

As it happens, I would say that they have developed in very similar ways. They have both gotten rid of nearly all case forms throughout the language, but maintained a greater level of case distinction in the personal pronouns than elsewhere (Spanish maintaining three cases in some pronouns, English managing only two); and if we limit ourselves to at least some *voseo*-speaking areas, they have also both gone through a shift where the second person plural became used to signify politeness, followed by the singular being perceived as *impolite* and subsequently all but dropped entirely; and the original plural being then used mainly as a singular, from which a separate plural must be secondarily formed.

If you ask me, that’s quite a parallel thing to do—though it must be mentioned that it is in no way a *rare* thing for Indo-European languages to do. Rather the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

English developed differently from Spanish because of their origins. Spanish is almost exclusively a Romance language, arising from Latin. English is only partly derived from Latin. It also has roots in Germanic, Celtic & Anglo-Saxon languages, which give it different verb forms, sentence structures and pronouns, among other things.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.  It should just be a comment.

Comment: This is in fact (intended to be) a partial answer to the question, specifically to "And what's so different about English that causes it to not develop in the way that Spanish does?"

Comment: Per Tolkien, an authority on such matters if ever there was one, [there’s no such thing as a language named “Anglo-Saxon”](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/95?m=10136006#10136006).  And English has much more Norse influence in it than it has Celtic.  Both Old English and Old Norse are Germanic languages, so that covers both bases.

Comment: Various modern Celtic and Germanic languages also have *vos* forms, so simply noting that English is not a Romance language does not explain its lack of one.

Comment: Spanish is not ‘almost’ exclusively a Romance language—it _is_ a Romance language. English does not derive from Latin at all, nor does it have roots in Celtic languages—it is a Germanic language, and it has its roots in Anglo-Saxon languages, which form one section of the Germanic languages. @choster What exactly do you mean by _vos_ forms here? Specifically plural forms (= _vosotros_)? Or singular, informal forms not based on a _t_-initial pronoun? If the latter, then I don’t think there are any modern Celtic or Germanic languages that have counterparts.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Sloppy layman usage on my part; I mean a polite or formal form. Specifically, I remember learning about Gaelic *sibh* vs. *tu*, though *sibh* has generally died out in Irish.

Comment: @choster Gotcha! Welsh _chwi_ is also used formally, like Scottish _sibh_. (I can't remember the Cornish or Breton forms off the top of my head.)